# Splunk convert Wed Sep 23 08:00:00 PDT 2020 to _time and epoch time in splunk

Tags: datetime, splunk

Splunk convert Wed Sep 23 08:00:00 PDT 2020 to _time and epoch time in splunk . What is the splunk query to convert java date format to yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.6/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strptime.28X.2CY.29

`| eval date_unix_timestamp=strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 0):

To convert time strings from one format to another you must `strptime()` convert to epoch form and then use `strftime()` to convert to the desired result format.

```
... | eval newTS=strftime(strptime("Wed Sep 23 08:00:00 PDT 2020", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%:S %Z %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: | makeresults | eval  newTS=strftime(strptime("Wed Sep 23 08:00:00 PDT 2020", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%:S %Z %Y"), "%Y-%m-%d") When I run this i get an error. Error in 'eval' command: The arguments to the 'strptime' function are invalid.

Comment: It may not like the literal string as an argument.  Try putting the value into a field and passing the field to `strptime()`.